# Jquery quotes in links

Tags: jquery, double-quotes

I have problem with plugin slider in wordpress , the basic problem it´s that insert this \ when detect this double quotes or single

For example :

```
footer_loader('http://website.com/index.php?action=contact/);
```

The plugin when save this link change the format to :

```
 footer_loader(\'http://website.com/index.php?action=contact/\);
```

It´s possible with jquery writte this function different for works ?

Because i have input field in plugin for only insert the link and for works need put this function and load ok the page with jquery

Regards !

Comment: your string is missing the closing `'`

Comment: yes error mine when i put here and forget this single quote , but the problem it´s the plugin add this slash to the link and by this no work me and the question it´s about it´s possible run this if no use never quotes

Comment: what if you save the string to a `variable` then use `footer_loader(variablename)` ?

Comment: aha nice idea i go try , thank´s !!!